# Laravel filament dependant field empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I have one database column that I want to dynamically be a FileUpload or a TextInput. The TextInput however, is always empty. If I remove the FileUpload the TextInput is filled.

```
return $form
            ->schema([
                Select::make('type')
                    ->options(['image' => 'image', 'link' => 'link'])
                    ->default('image')
                    ->required()
                    ->reactive(),
                FileUpload::make('link')
                    ->reactive()
                    ->image()
                    ->disk('s3')
                    ->directory(function (RelationManager $livewire): string {
                        return ProductMediaService::getUploadDirectory($livewire->ownerRecord);
                    })
                    ->getUploadedFileNameForStorageUsing(function (TemporaryUploadedFile $file, RelationManager $livewire): string {
                        return ProductMediaService::getFileName($livewire->ownerRecord, $file->getClientOriginalExtension());
                    })
                    ->when(fn (Closure $get) => $get('type') === 'image'),
                TextInput::make('link')
                    ->reactive()
                    ->afterStateHydrated(function (TextInput $component, $state) {
                        $component->state($state);
                    })
                    ->when(fn (Closure $get) => $get('type') === 'link'),
                TextInput::make('title'),
                TextInput::make('subtitle'),
                TextInput::make('source'),
                Toggle::make('is_logo'),
                Toggle::make('is_cover'),
```

Tried different versions of when() like hidden(), also did not work.

Anyone an idea how I can do it differently?

Comment: Show `type` checkbox or toggle also.. and which version you're using?

Comment: @Vpa Version = 2.17.53

What do you mean with "Show type checkbox or toggle also"?

Comment: You have `$get('type')` and show `ToggleOrCheckbox::make('type')` don't how to put a word for this

Comment: Show components where you use `make('type')` I think components word is correct :)

Comment: Ahhh sorry, no it is correct, and it works, it switches between Upload and Input, the upload works perfectly, the Input is just empty (while there is a value). Edited the post with full code.

Comment: Ok, just to be clear when you select `image` then fileUpload with image is showing, but when you select `link` textInput showing without data, even if you have `link` data in database, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, but it may not work :) IIRC they need to have dynamic `make('dynamic')`

```php
Select::make('type')
    ->options(['image' => 'image', 'link' => 'link'])
    ->default('image')
    ->required()
    ->reactive(),
    
FileUpload::make('link')
    // ->reactive() // no need unless you want something to change after file uploaded
    ->image()
    ->disk('s3')
    ->directory(function (RelationManager $livewire): string {
        return ProductMediaService::getUploadDirectory($livewire->ownerRecord);
    })
    ->getUploadedFileNameForStorageUsing(function (TemporaryUploadedFile $file, RelationManager $livewire): string {
        return ProductMediaService::getFileName($livewire->ownerRecord, $file->getClientOriginalExtension());
    })
    ->when(fn (Closure $get) => $get('type') === 'image'),

TextInput::make('link')
    // ->reactive() // no need unless you want to change something after text entered
    // Below part are not require imo if your table is set up correctly
    // ->afterStateHydrated(function (TextInput $component, $state) {
    //    $component->state($state);
    // })
    ->when(fn (Closure $get) => $get('type') === 'link'),
```

I would suggest to have different column like `image` and `link` with `nullable()` and call like

```php
FileUpload::make('image'),

TextInput::make('link'),
```

Comment: Ah yeah that is a leftover from trying different things, that is not supposed to be there :-D

Not having different fields is a requirement in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this already to create a filament plugin, build the array before and pass it to the $form only when "ready", this way you can handle the field conditional printing in an easier way.

```
$schema = [
            Select::make('type')
                ->options(['image' => 'image', 'link' => 'link'])
                ->default('image')
                ->required()
                ->reactive(),];
    
    if ( $link_is_file_upload ) { //Your condition here
        $schema_link = [
            FileUpload::make('link')
        ];
    } else {
        $schema_link = [
            TextInput::make('link')
        ];
    }
    
    $schema_additional = [
        TextInput::make('title'),
        TextInput::make('subtitle'),
        TextInput::make('source'),
        Toggle::make('is_logo'),
        Toggle::make('is_cover'),
    ];
    
    array_push( $schema, $schema_link, $schema_additional ); //or $schema[] = $schema_link;
    
    return $form
        ->schema($schema);
```